# Multiple replicas accessing a cache in kubernetes

Tags: go, kubernetes, microservices, prometheus

One statistic for Prometheus logging is the duration of service calls but I want to measure the time over multiple calls of the same service.

So I figured to create a map of string to time.Time

```
type SomeService struct {
    durations map[string]time.Time
}
```

On first entry the current time is stored for that account id

```
durations[GetId()] = time.Now()
```

And then in the end…in another call…the total time is stored.

```
startTime := c.durations[id]
duration, _ := c.durationStat.GetMetricWith(prometheus.Labels{"type": duration})
duration.Set(time.Now().Sub(startTime).Seconds())
delete(c.durations, id)
```

This works when there is only one replica but it breaks down in a Kubernetes cluster right? The next call might come in on another endpoint? How do you cache values in microservices so that every replica can access them?

Comment: could you please also add the error that occurs for your implementation?

Comment: I've been told that you cant cache like this, there is no error

Comment: Just looking for a good way how to do it easily

Comment: I'm not sure what you're caching here as this is the first time I see someone use Prometheus for something other than gathering metrics. General problem of handling cache between multiple instances is data consistency because of the fact that data for the same cache key can be re-written between different instances.

Comment: By "the next call might come in on another endpoint" do you mean you have separate separate requests for "start service call" and "end service call"? Or simply that you may get different "service calls" (each consisting of "start service call", useful work, and "end service call") handled by different replicas?

Comment: The word session triggered a google search on "kubernetes session" and that came up with: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/ You can configure the service to have the same ip address always go to the same pod by setting service.spec.sessionAffinity to “ClientIP”!

Comment: Your metric collection code has some fundamental issues. You try to collect timings on a per-ID basis but then record only one gauge value with the value in seconds which means last write wins and no meaningful data is collected.
You should look into using a histogram or summary when collecting timings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found this:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service

> You can configure the service to have the same ip address always go to
>   the same pod by setting service.spec.sessionAffinity to “ClientIP” the
>   default is “None”

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  selector:
    app: MyApp
```

This way you can safely cache simple values in memory!

Comment: Is the requirement to track these timings across multiple API requests? If yes, then sessionAffinity will only help so much. Pods come and go (esp when scaling up and down a lot) and there's no guarantee the pod that recorded the start time is still around later in the life cycle.